# Can't locate node laser_scan_filters

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to filter the angles of the laser scans and wrote a launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="laser_filters" type="laser_scan_filters" output="screen" name="laser_scan">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find laser_filters)/launch/angle_filter.yaml" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

However, when I try to execute it, I get this error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [laser_filters/laser_scan_filters]: can't locate node [laser_scan_filters] in package [laser_filters]
```

Which is quite strange as there is a c++ executable in CMakeLists.
Here is an example of CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(laser_filters)

##############################################################################
# Find dependencies
##############################################################################

set(THIS_PACKAGE_ROS_DEPS sensor_msgs roscpp tf filters message_filters
  laser_geometry pluginlib angles)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${THIS_PACKAGE_ROS_DEPS})
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system signals)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

##############################################################################
# Define package
##############################################################################

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES pointcloud_filters laser_scan_filters
  CATKIN_DEPENDS ${THIS_PACKAGE_ROS_DEPS}
  DEPENDS
  )

##############################################################################
# Build
##############################################################################

add_library(pointcloud_filters src/pointcloud_filters.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pointcloud_filters ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_library(laser_scan_filters src/laser_scan_filters.cpp src/median_filter.cpp src/array_filter.cpp src/box_filter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(laser_scan_filters ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(scan_to_cloud_filter_chain src/scan_to_cloud_filter_chain.cpp)
target_link_libraries(scan_to_cloud_filter_chain ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(scan_to_scan_filter_chain src/scan_to_scan_filter_chain.cpp)
target_link_libraries(scan_to_scan_filter_chain ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(generic_laser_filter_node src/generic_laser_filter_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(generic_laser_filter_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  find_package(rostest)
  add_executable(test_scan_filter_chain test/test_scan_filter_chain.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(test_scan_filter_chain laser_scan_filters ${rostest_LIBRARIES} gtest)
  add_dependencies(test_scan_filter_chain gtest)

  add_rostest(test/test_scan_filter_chain.launch)

  catkin_add_gtest(test_shadow_detector test/test_shadow_detector.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(test_shadow_detector ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${rostest_LIBRARIES})
endif()

##############################################################################
# Install
##############################################################################

install(TARGETS pointcloud_filters laser_scan_filters 
  scan_to_cloud_filter_chain
  scan_to_scan_filter_chain
  generic_laser_filter_node
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

# Install headers
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})

install(FILES laser_filters_plugins.xml
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311175/can%27t-locate-node-laser_scan_filters/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2018-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on 2018-12-20**:
did you try to source your workspace ??? (source devel/setup.bash)

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2018-12-20**:
@zubair of course, it is hardcoded in my bashrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have created a *library* called `laser_scan_filters` not an executable, this is the cause of your problem. Libraries will only execute if they are linked to by an executable binary, they cannot be run independently themselves.

```
add_library(laser_scan_filters src/laser_scan_filters.cpp src/median_filter.cpp src/array_filter.cpp src/box_filter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(laser_scan_filters ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

You need to change this to:

```
add_executable(laser_scan_filters src/laser_scan_filters.cpp src/median_filter.cpp src/array_filter.cpp src/box_filter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(laser_scan_filters ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Hope this helps.

Update:

Looking at the [documentation for laser_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#Laser_Filter_Nodes) you need to start the scan_to_scan_filter_chain node and specify the filters you want to put in that chain in a YAML file.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-20**:
Isn't the `CMakeLists.txt` the OP shows the regular one from the [laser_filters](https://github.com/ros-perception/laser_filters/blob/074a2285921baf4e36fe6336eabd7731317904d1/CMakeLists.txt) package?

In that case the libraries are supposed to be there.

I'm confused by the text in the OP.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-20**:
That would make sense if they're building it from source. The laser_filters are libraries not nodes, this may be the source of the problem.